# ASPNET Core Routing

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I had a problem with incorrect route setup, which I've fixed, but I don't fully understand why the fix worked.

```cs
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")
    public class DetailsController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/[controller]/{transactNo}")]
        public IActionResult Detail(int transactNo)
        {
        ...
```

When I was calling `api/details/123` I was getting route not found, until I removed the `Route` attribute from the class.  So I guess they were conflicting, but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The endpoint's route is the controller's route `api/[controller]` concatenated with the action's route `api/[controller]/{transactNo}`.

In your case, the endpoint's route is `api/[controller]/api/[controller]/{transactNo}`.

You need simplify the action's route like :

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("{transactNo}")]
public IActionResult Detail(int transactNo)
{
```

If you want redefine the endpoint's route only from the action, the action's route have to begin with `/` :

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("/api/[controller]/{transactNo}")]
public IActionResult Detail(int transactNo)
{
```

Answer (score 2):

Placing a `RouteAttribute` on a controller is different to placing one on an action.

- On a controller, it defines the route that all actions belonging to that controller will be prefixed with
- On an action, it defines the route to be concatenated with the prefixed route

That means when you added both attributes, you would have been able to call the action at:

```
https://localhost:44338/api/details/api/details/1
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                  from controller         ^
                                    from action
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace route attribtue on action to `[HttpGet("{transactNo}")]` and change the route attribute on the controller to `[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]`

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class DetailsController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("{transactNo}")]
    public IActionResult Detail(int transactNo)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

now you can call this url : `api/Details/Detail/123`